# autocomplete to search from right side if charecters length is 3?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i have a code and description in my input autocomplete bar here is example

```
LONDON HETHREW LHR

LONDON   LON

NEWYORK NYC
```

now i want my autocomplete to search from right side only when input charecter string is of length 3

if length is greater then 4 it searches from left side here what i am adapting method only

```
$("#tags2").autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  minLength: 3
});
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is little bit tricky as you stated.So I am writing an answer based on my understanding.

> Case 1 : If input length is greater than 3 -> match from end
>
> Case 2 : If input length is greater than 4 -> match from start

Code can look like this.I haven't tested fully,however it should work.

Basically in response callback there is a checking on the length of request to track the number of characters being typed and based on that either matching from start or end would be applied.

```
$("#selector").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        response($.map(modelData, function (value, key) {
                            if (request.term.length > 4 && value.Label.toLowerCase().startsWith(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
                                return {
                                    label: value.Label                                        
                                };
                            }
                            else if(request.term.length > 3 && request.term.length <= 4 && value.Label.toLowerCase().endsWith(request.term.toLowerCase())){
                                return {
                                    label: value.Label                                                 
                                };
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    select: function (e, i) {
                        $("#selector").val(i.item.label);                          
                        return false;
                    },
                    minLength: 3, //minLength set to 3 as minimum 3 letters to be typed
                    scroll: true
                });
```

And the string extension methods are:

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function (str) {
            return this.substring(0, str.length) === str;
};

String.prototype.endsWith = function(str, suffix) {
    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};
```

**Edit**

According to [autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) documentation :

```
select( e, i )
```

> Triggered when an item is selected from the menu. The default action is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item.
>
> e
>     Type: Event
>
> i
>     Type: Object
>     item Type: Object

An Object with label and value properties for the selected option.

Comment: length equal to 3 then from right if greater then 3 then left

Comment: string extension methods ? where to right this in code

Comment: yes you can adjust the condition based on your req.and you need to write string extenstion methods inside document.ready.those are just like functions.

Comment: my string name is `availabletags` that have all list of value so this is my datasource

Comment: abviously `modelData` replaced by `availabletags`

Comment: all values are upper cased too i am right in above comments about source

Comment: yes replace `modelData` with `availabletags` and if it is flat structure then remove key parameter which is unnecessary.Using `toLowerCase` ensures that irrespective of user types in uppercase or lowercase match will occur.

Comment: The source like that `var availabletags = ["LONDON LON" , "LAHORE LHE" , "NEW YORK  NYC" , "DUBAI BDX"];`
so there is no `key` so `function (value, key) {`  will be `function (value) {` and what about  last function  `function (e, i) {`

Comment: @AIRTRAVELS updated answer with details of select and documentation link.